# Adjusting a table that compares covariance matrices?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, matrices

Hee everyone,

I'm making this table that compares covariance matrices but I can't get two things done that I want. First of all I want the matrices to be the exact same size (the top ones seem to be bigger now). Second, I would like to see the Sigma+arrow above the other two matrices too.

Can someone please help me out? [image]

My code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Covariance matrices using IME and sandwich form}\label{tab:2}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\columnwidth, center}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c}
\toprule
 \textbf{Normally distributed errors} & \textbf{Student-t distributed errors} \\ 
\midrule 
$\Sigma_{IME}(\theta)$: \Longrightarrow \\ \[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \num{-2.05e-4} & \num{-7.16e-10} & \num{-2.42e-08} \\ \num{-7.16e-10} & \num{2.05e-04} & \num{2.71e-05} \\ \num{-2.42e-08} & \num{2.71e-05} & \num{2.64e-03} \end{array}\right]\]   & \[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \num{2.04e-08} & \num{-3.82e-12} & \num{-8.77e-12} \\ \num{-3.82e-12} & \num{4.11e-08} & \num{5.43e-09} \\ \num{-8.77e-12} & \num{5.43e-09} & \num{5.28e-07} \end{array}\right]\]  \\ 
$\Sigma_{Sandwich}(\theta)$: \Longrightarrow \\ \[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \num{6.58e-01} & \num{-1.64e-05} & \num{1.31e-04} \\ \num{-1.64e-05} & \num{2.04e-04} & \num{2.72e-05} \\ \num{1.31e-04} & \num{2.72e-05} & \num{2.64e-03}  \end{array}\right]\] & \[\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \num{2.06e-08} & \num{3.85e-12} & \num{8.82e-12} \\ \num{3.85e-12} & \num{4.11e-08} & \num{5.44e-09} \\ \num{8.82e-12} & \num{5.44e-09} & \num{5.29e-07} \end{array}\right]\] \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]            
\end{tabular*}
\end{adjustbox}
\centering
\end{table
```

Comment: Note: if someone can make this table fit on a page with the Sigma's being a separate column on the left, then I'm even happier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if someone can make this table fit on a page with the Sigmas being a separate column on the left, then I'm even happier!

Hoping to make you happy :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,amssymb}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2e-2,tight-spacing}
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default: 5pt
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\caption{Covariance matrices using IME and sandwich form\strut}\label{tab:2}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} RCC}
\toprule
& \text{Normally distributed errors}
& \text{Student-$t$ distributed errors} \\ 
\midrule 
\Sigma_{\textrm{IME}}(\theta): \Longrightarrow &
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}SSS@{}} 
-2.05e-4  & -7.16e-10 & -2.42e-08 \\ 
-7.16e-10 &  2.05e-04 &  2.71e-05 \\ 
-2.42e-08 &  2.71e-05 &  2.64e-03
\end{array}\right]
  & 
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}SSS@{}} 
 2.04e-08 & -3.82e-12 & -8.77e-12 \\ 
-3.82e-12 &  4.11e-08 &  5.43e-09 \\ 
-8.77e-12 &  5.43e-09 &  5.28e-07 
\end{array}\right]
\\  \addlinespace
\Sigma_{\textrm{Sandwich}}(\theta): \Longrightarrow &
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}SSS@{}} 
 6.58e-01 & -1.64e-05 & 1.31e-04 \\ 
-1.64e-05 &  2.04e-04 & 2.72e-05 \\ 
 1.31e-04 &  2.72e-05 & 2.64e-03  
\end{array}\right]
 & 
\left[ \begin{array}{@{}SSS@{}} 
2.06e-08 & 3.85e-12 & 8.82e-12 \\ 
3.85e-12 & 4.11e-08 & 5.44e-09 \\ 
8.82e-12 & 5.44e-09 & 5.29e-07 
\end{array}\right]
\\
\bottomrule           
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico and Zarko!!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

With use of the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{table-number-alignment = center,
             table-figures-integer = 2,
             table-figures-decimal = 2,
             table-figures-exponent = 2,
             }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}

\caption{Covariance matrices using IME and sandwich form}
\label{tab:2}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ *{2}{>{$}X<{$}} }
    \toprule
    \addlinespace
    \textbf{Normally distributed errors}
    &   \textbf{Student-t distributed errors}       \\
    \midrule
\Sigma_{\text{IME}}(\theta):\quad \Longrightarrow
    &                           \\
    \left[\begin{tabular}{SSS}
-2.05e-4    &   -7.16e-10   &   -2.42e-08       \\
-7.16e-10   &    2.05e-04   &    2.71e-05       \\
-2.42e-08   &    2.71e-05   &   2.64e-03
    \end{tabular}\right]
    &   \left[\begin{tabular}{SSS}
     2.04e-08   &   -3.82e-12   &   -8.77e-12   \\
    -3.82e-12   &    4.11e-08   &    5.43e-09   \\
    -8.77e-12   &    5.43e-09   &    5.28e-07
    \end{tabular}\right]        \\
% second row
    \addlinespace
\Sigma_{\text{Sandwich}}(\theta):\quad \Longrightarrow
    &                           \\ 
    \left[\begin{tabular}{SSS}
 6.58e-01   &   -1.64e-05   &   1.31e-04        \\
-1.64e-05   &    2.04e-04   &   2.72e-05        \\
 1.31e-04   &    2.72e-05   &   2.64e-03  
    \end{tabular}\right]
    &   \left[\begin{tabular}{SSS}
    2.06e-08    &   3.85e-12    &   8.82e-12    \\
    3.85e-12    &   4.11e-08    &   5.44e-09    \\
    8.82e-12    &   5.44e-09    &   5.29e-07
        \end{tabular}\right]    \\
    \addlinespace
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```